# Pickle a randomly generated password to another Python script

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a function which creates a randomly generated password. The password then gets passed into `zip_test` which creates a zip file using the same password.

Both functions are on the same script.

```
import string
import random
import subprocess

def password_generator():
  chars = string.ascii_uppercase + string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits + '!@#$%^&*(|<>,.)'
  size = random.randint(8, 12)
  return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for x in range(size))

def zip_file():
    random_pass =password_generator()
    command_zip = 'zip -j -r -e -P{0} /test.zip /dir'.format(random_pass).split()
    subprocess.call(command_zip)
    return random_pass
```

On another .py script I want to send an email which basically says:

`"Hi, this is your password: <password> to open the zip file"`

Is there a way to pickle it so that the password in the email matches the password used to encrypt the zip file?

Or perhaps there is an easier way to do this that I may be missing?

Comment: what do you mean pickle it. You can just save the password in a text file if you want to save it, don't go pickling a string object

Comment: What is so bad about pickling a string object? Genuinely curious. The reason why I don't want to store it in a text is because everytime the script is run off a cron job, I want the password to be different. Of course I could always delete the contents of the txt after the script is run, but I thought there would be a simpler way.

Comment: I'll go the store in txt route for now. Thank you.